# how to convert feature_log_prob_ to exponential feature importance for BernoulliNB

Tags: machine-learning, python, naive-bayes-classifier, python-3.x

I am using BernoulliNB classification for problem

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
clf2 = BernoulliNB()
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
y__NB__prediction=clf2.predict(X_test)
sk_report = classification_report(
                  digits=2,
                  y_true=y_test, 
                  y_pred=y__NB__prediction)
print(sk_report)
```

for calculating feature importance i am using `feature_log_prob_`. But there are a few issues for me:

1. `feature_log_prob_`  depends on the number of classes and the number of features for each class, but how to determine which class it belongs to.?
2. `feature_log_prob_` don't give the probability directly but its logarithm. So you need to apply exponential in order to get back the probability. How should this be done?